# mavenized apache SDK not available

Tags: apache, apache-flex

I see that apache has the Mavenizer project to mavenize it's FLEX SDK .

Is there any already available maven artifacts of the sdk on the web . or at lest planning to do So ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thread on the subject… basically maven wouldn't be able to resolve the dependencies needed to get a project to build because Adobe doesn't want to mavenize the flash player or adobe air sdk.

Blame Adobe.

http://apache-flex-users.2333346.n4.nabble.com/4-10-0-Maven-Artifacts-tt2616.html#a2622

As a workaround you can download all the artifacts yourself and upload them to your own artifact repository.

Comment: yup and this does not make sense :)